# Dropbox system tray icon missing, not working

Tags: linux, dropbox, lubuntu

On an Lubuntu 15.10 machine the Dropbox icon, which tells the state of the application and allows interaction, is missing.

When I start Dropbox, no matter if I'm using `dropbox start`, `dropbox start -i` or the `lxpanel`-bookmark, only a small camera icon appears in the "Indicator Applets"-section of `lxpanel`: [image: Camera icon instead of dropbox icon]

This is very annoying, since I always have to use the terminal to check on the status. What's the reason of this weird behavior? It used to work some time ago, I can't tell when it changed, probably a software update. Reinstalling doesn't work, and the icons exist in the `~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86-3.14.5/images/hicolor/16x16/status`-directory.

Comment: This issue is also documented at http://askubuntu.com/q/732967/41313 and on the Dropbox forum at https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205739106-Stable-Build-3-14-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, most of the answers here are pure voodoo and do not address the actual underlying issues, of which there are two (I'm writing this in part so that I don't forget it myself the next time I'm dealing with this).

Issue number one: Dropbox attempts to fit to whatever environment it runs under, so it does some autodetection work. It sometimes fails, as it's not been updated since 2015. This issue has been addressed by an updated `/usr/bin/dropbox` wrapper as shipped in Ubuntu's `nautilus-dropbox` package. So if you want to avoid part of the issues, use it, not the package Dropbox provides. If not, make sure `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is set to `Unity` before Dropbox runs; the Ubuntu version of the package does this internally.

Issue number two: Dropbox is written using Qt, more precisely Qt5. Unity is based mostly on GTK+. Qt can use GTK+ styles, but the implementation has changed significantly in the recent year or so. <s>Unfortunately, the default install of Ubuntu doesn't make it easy to use GTK+ styles from Qt, since `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` is by default set to `gtk`</s>, which doesn't work as expected, and GTK+ styling fails to initialise, which leads to unavailability of everything based on GTK+ including the D-Bus menu interface, which is what makes the indicator work. Unsetting `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` or setting it to a valid value unbreaks Dropbox and makes the indicator appear again.

**Update:**  Actually, it’s not an Ubuntu default, but something else may be setting the variable to a wrong value — in my case, it was `~/.xsession` where I’ve put it some years ago and forgot about it. In any case, it is worth checking and possibly force-setting it to the correct value.

Comment: The other answer,  `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start` works for me. https://superuser.com/a/1043469/379553 as of Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: This is the only answer that works for me in XFCE  on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 25):

Lubuntu 14.04 ....I have a few machines, all the same OS. One by one Dropbox icon dissappeared.

I have struggled for months. Couldn't recover icon.
Got it now!

1. In terminal type ... `dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`
2. Follow the prompts, if any. Two of my machines responded "Dropbox not installed".
3. `sudo apt-get install dropbox`
4. Repeat line 1. Icon appeared. Didn't stay after re-boot.
5. Repeat line 1, to get icon.
6. Go to Preferences ...General, (Dropbox icon) and un-tick 'Start Dropbox on system startup'.
7. Now to 'Default applications for LXSession' (menu ...Preferences)
8. Under Autostart, un-tick any previous Dropbox attempts (these can be deleted later).
9. Add `dbus-launch dropbox start`
10. Re-boot.

Answer (score 20):

There are some workarounds until the bug is fixed. The best one at this moment (working for Linux distros such as Xubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.) is:

```
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```

More details at another StackExchange site: [Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/736205/506976)

**Update:**

And a [more recent workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/739018/506976) that works for more Linux operating systems:

```
dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start
```

Comment: Finally the solution, the second works for me

Comment: The second solution worked for me as well, thanks! Still, I'll mark @ecosseman 's answer as accepted, since his answer is more detailed and describes a permanent fix.

Comment: Finally, works for me too!!! Thank you. Simply stopping and starting the daemon wasn't doing anything to the icon.

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked for me too on Kubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for Lubuntu 17.04 is (assuming that you have downloaded a .deb file):

1) Make a copy of Dropbox autostart file:
    `cp ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/.config/autostart/newstart_dropbox.desktop` 
2) Edit the file newstart_dropbox.desktop. Change the `Exec=` line to

`Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i`;

3) Copy the file in /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/:
    `cp /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
4)Edit the file that you copied to `~/.local/share/applications/` like you did in step 2. Change the `Exec=` line to

`Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i`

5) Disable Dropbox autostart, with the following command on terminal:
    `dropbox autostart n`

Thanks for Andrew and the Wepup8 team for the tips.
http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/fix-dropbox-indicator-icon-and-menu-not.html

Comment: works in ubuntu 16.06 too

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/fix-dropbox-indicator-icon-and-menu-not.html

Answer (score 3):

As I had the same problem with Debian 9 (cinnamon) after an upgrade, and here it is what I have done:
I edited the file `/user/share/applications/desktop.dropbox` and changed the line `Exec=dropbox start -i` to `Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i`.

Also added a line to delay the start of dropbox: `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=30`
I had to reboot as well.

Answer (score 1):

Juan, I have found that neither of those workarounds is working specifically in **Lubuntu**. When I updated to Lubuntu 15.10, I got the same problem of a non-functional indicator area icon as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64/739018#739018

However, the only thing I have found to work for Lubuntu is this:

1. `dropbox stop`
2. `dbus-launch ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`
3. That will start dropbox with the system tray ("notification area") icon, instead of the nonfunctional "indicator area" icon. So, go into Dropbox settings via the icon that should now be working, and TURN OFF the check box to start dropbox automatically. Also, just to be sure, issue the following in terminal:
4. `dropbox autostart n`
5. `gksudo pcmanfm`
6. in the elevated-permissions file manager window, go to folder /bin and create a file called "dropbox-workaround-autostart". In it put:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> dbus-launch ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

6. Right-click the file, and in permissions tab, make executable for Anyone.
7. Go to Preferences>Default applications for LXSession>Autostart, and under the "manual" section input box, type the name of the file (dropbox-workaround-autostart) and hit add.

That's got it consistently working for me know. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Launching Dropbox with `dbus-launch` causes the new-style indicator to work properly, rather than causing it to use the old-style X tray icon.  Also, you don't need to make a new script in `/bin` for this (and you shouldn't be putting things in `/bin` anyway; use `~/.local/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`).  Just put the command `dbus-launch dropbox start` directly into the Autostart dialog.

Comment: Your method probably works as well as @ecosseman 's answer, but I'll still mark his answer as accepted, since putting the `dbus launch`-command directly in the autostart manager is to be preferred over writing a script in /bin.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Lubuntu and worked perfectly.

```
cp ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/.config/autostart/start_dropbox.desktop
sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i/' ~/.config/autostart/start_dropbox.desktop
dropbox autostart n
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=dbus-launch dropbox start -i/' ~/.local/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/fix-dropbox-indicator-icon-and-menu-not.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Arch Linux user with GNOME3 Desktop.
In my case I need to add some delay when audostart:

1. Make a bash file anywhere you want. (e.g. `~/dropbox_delay.sh`)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   sleep 30
   dropbox
   ```
2. Give it an execute permission: `chmod +x ~/dropbox_delay.sh`
3. In `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop` file edit the following line (or a similar line starting with `Exec=`:

   ```
   Exec=dropbox
   ```

   to

   ```
   Exec=/home/_your_home_/dropbox_delay.sh
   ```
4. Do the same in `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

If Dropbox is started as a cronjob need to set environment $DISPLAY for the display.

Add a test to see if X is running and if so set the $DISPLAY before restarting Dropbox.

If $DISPLAY is not set, script will restart Dropbox anyway.

Testing for $DISPLAY allows this script restart Dropbox while user is not logged into X.

Having this script run on start of X session will restart Dropbox and enable icon to appear

eg for ~/bin/dropbox-start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $DISPLAY ]]
    then export DISPLAY=:0
fi
dropbox stop &&
sleep 30 &&
dbus-launch dropbox start -i
```

Works for LinuxMint 17.3 running XFCE4

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown menu is not working, but the indicator is showing, while using MATE, try installing `caja-dropbox` instead of `dropbox`.

See:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/caja-dropbox-not-showing-popup-menu-after-starting-mate-17-10/15780/4